# Keep a background thread alive while it is listening for events from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, awesomium

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Without blocking the main thread, I want to use [`Awesomium.NET`](http://www.awesomium.com) to load a web page, manipulate the DOM and do some processing, then return some data to the main thread.

In my background thread, I create a `WebView` (essentially represents a tab in a web browser), then subscribe to its `LoadingFrameComplete` event (fires when the `WebView` has loaded a given URL). I then initiate the loading of the URL.

The problem is that the loading of the URL doesn't block the current thread. This means that right after the background thread tells the `WebView` to load the URL, the thread finishes.

Once the `WebView` actually finishes loading the URL, the background thread, which was listening for the `LoadingFrameComplete` event, is no longer alive and so it can't do the data processing.

This of course means that no data is returned to the main thread for display..

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the product, but why are you not doing something like this in your thread, as is shown right in the snippet on the linked site? `while(view->IsLoading()) core->Update();` Seems like that is the loop that keeps processing until the load is complete...

Comment: @DarkFalcon Well, I'll be damned... I somehow managed to miss that part. It worked perfectly. Unfortunately,  `WebCore#Update` is deprecated and will be removed in the next version.

I had the entire thing working earlier, when I ran the thing on the main thread to familiarize myself with Awesomium.  
The way I did it was by correctly (and unknowingly) using `WebCore#Update`'s replacement.  However, when I moved it to a background thread, I wasn't aware of the extra things I am supposed to do.

Once I get it running, I'll post the solution, if no one has posted a suitable answer.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dark Falcon's comment, I was able to find the solution to my problem.

It turns out it's as simple as calling [`WebCore#Run`](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_WebCore_Run.htm) and [`WebCore#Shutdown`](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_WebCore_Shutdown.htm).

Create the background thread and on that thread, create the `WebView`, subcribe to the `LoadingFrameComplete` event, initialize the web page load, then call `WebCore#Run`.
This makes the thread run until `WebCore#Shutdown` is called.

In the `LoadingFrameComplete` event handler, do the processing, then call `WebCore#Shutdown`. This causes the thread to resume from the point where `WebCore#Run` was called. Since it was called as the last thing on the thread, the thread will exit.